# AspNet Membership: Warning: Fatal error 9001 occurred

Tags: asp.net-membership

I'm setting up a new website and the site uses asp.net membership. This was working fine but today when I try and log in or do anything such as add a new user/role in the asp.net configuration wizard I get:

```
Warning: Fatal error 9001 occurred at Jul 30 2012  7:52PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.
```

Searching online, it seems to suggest that the logs are full, but I'm advised by the website host that there is ample free space, so I dont really know what to try next.

Has anyone come accross this before and if so, how did you manage to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was a database issue. I couldn't even create a new table or drop a table and ultimately had to get the database restored, which solved everything.

Comment: Please contact me at marco.marsala AT live.it to see if our solution is applicable in your case to definitely solve the root cause of this annoying issue

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem recently too and after mountains of research it appears to be common when a database is set to AUTO CLOSE. I set all the databases to AUTO CLOSE = FALSE. This started with one database then went over to two and the next it was on all of them. I simply restarted the SQL Server Instance Service instead of restoring databases. Another way to fix the symptom is to take the problematic database offline and bring it back online again.

Comment: Please contact me at marco.marsala AT live.it to see if our solution is applicable in your case to definitely solve the root cause of this annoying issue